# Huawei ads and IAP not working with original IDS

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, ads, huawei-mobile-services

I'm developing the huawei game in unity i integrate huawei ads and iap but when i play it on test ids on device it show ads but not with the original ids

Comment: Are original ids formal ad unit IDs? If you want to display ads in the formal ad slot ID, you need to check whether your application has been released. You can follow [this link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/monetize/release-0000001050961874) to test.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has not been published in Huawei AG, you will have to use test IDs to test Ads instead of the actual Ads id to test. Otherwise, you won't see Huawei Ads. Some of the reference info. for you:

Banner test id: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-banner-0000001050066915#section1119713111418
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

For IAP, you will need to do sandbox testing before release: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/sandbox-testing-0000001050035039